# regex how to find /,-,/s,,,! in one example?

Tags: javascript, regex

How to find non letters from expression ?
example string " friday is piątek, but in different language!"
i did that but without efford :

```
elem1 = element.replace(/\s/g, '');
elem2 = elem1.replace(/\-/g, '');
elem3 = elem2.replace(/,/g, '');
elem4 = elem3.replace(/!/g, '')
elem = elem4.replace(/\//g, '');
```

I cant use /W because that will find letters like ł, 
i need: fridayispiątekbutindifferentlanguage

Comment: Non-English characters `[^a-zA-Z]+`

Comment: You have required only non english letter or special character also. Can you put some example.

Comment: i did example, i cant use [^a-zA-Z]+ becosue that will leave me a ","